# Android studio: No space left on device

Tags: java, android

I was experimenting with my android app but soon received a lot of errors [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNSQp.jpg).

First of all, I thought that it was a problem with an emulator, so I deleted some apps from it but nothing happened. After that I started googling and found that the problem could be fixed by AVD Manager --> Emulator --> Wipe Data but, again, nothing has changed.

Then I tried to delete emulator but all in vain.

So, now I even cannot close Android Studio because of this error.

How do I correct that?

I'm using OS X and Android Studio 2.2.2

UPD: Problem solved by restarting AS, sorry :(

Answer (score 3):

Those errors are from Android Studio, not the Android SDK. It means some part of your own hard disk has run out of space.

I suggest you check disk usage in the "About this Mac" program.

Comment: I checked that, I have more than 13GB free

Comment: Yep this was my problem - i thought it was referring to the phone!!!

Answer (score 3):

Add following bash variable in studio.sh at start of file

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp
```

Comment: This only work for linux , Looking for a solution for MacOS

Answer (score 2):

You can add below line to /etc/fstab to increase tmp size

```
none /tmp tmpfs size=8G 0 0
```

And then run below command with root account

```
mount -a
```

Please check it with:

```
df -h
```